# Gradle WAR with compiled classes under WEB-INF/classes

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, war

I'm trying to port a legacy Java webapp project into gradle.

This is a snippet of my build.gradle

```
def customBuildPath = 'build/classes'

war {
    from(customBuildPath) {
        into 'WEB-INF/classes'
    }

    from('WebContent') {
        include 'Web/**/*'
        into ''
    }
}

dependencies {
  
    compile fileTree(dir: 'projectlibs/lib', include:'*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'build/classes', include:'**')
}
```

To maintain the custom structure I want to put all my `*.class` files under `WEB-INF/classes` and it works, but I find also the same `*.class` files under `WEB-INF/lib`.

My goal it to keep jars and classes in separated war folder.

Any thoughts?

Edit: Added `dependencies{}` to the `build.gradle` snippet.

Comment: It’s hard to say why that happens without seeing more of your build configuration. Can you maybe provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks @Chriki. Reviewing build.gradle for answer your question pointed me to a wrong `dependecies` definition.

Comment: I figured that’d be the issue, glad to hear you could solve it yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem get solved with commenting out builded classes from the dependencies:

```
def customBuildPath = 'build/classes'

war {
    from(customBuildPath) {
        into 'WEB-INF/classes'
    }

    from('WebContent') {
        include 'Web/**/*'
        into ''
    }
}

dependencies {
  
    compile fileTree(dir: 'projectlibs/lib', include:'*.jar')
//    compile fileTree(dir: 'build/classes', include:'**')
}
```